# Whats the right way to set up view controllers?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm making a quiz game

You may all find this funny but its the only way I know how to d this!

I've set 35 logos on 35 view controllers, Is that acceptable or will apple not allow it?

Comment: Not funny, just a learning process. Not a massive description of what you have but if the user can't tell the difference then Apple won't mind inefficient coding.

Comment: It would really depend on what you are doing with these logos.

Comment: Well I have in total 233 view controllers lol!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple policy.

Answer (score 2):

Apple wont reject your app but it's bad practice. If you have a quiz game you could just make a view controller for the quiz which has a textview for the question and four buttons for the answers. The text for the buttons and the questions could be saved in a database like core data or in a simple plist file and when the quiz starts you load them from there.

You can find a tutorial for a little quiz app over here: [click me](http://www.raywenderlich.com/31814/objectively-speaking-2-a-crash-course-in-objective-c-for-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

there're many ways to do this.
you should look at `UIPageController` or `UICollectionViewController`

if that's not what you need, you can create it yourself, just make an `UIViewController` with `UIImageView` property and set its image.